# Selenium - Difficulty in finding element

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

The following is a snippet from firebug for the element i seek.
The element is on cell in a table, many of which will have the same state, So i cannot just check page source for "RUNNING"

```
<td>
<td id="name3" scope="row">
<td id="machineName3">Machine-0</td>
<td id="state3">RUNNING</td>
<td id="transitionActivity3">
</tr>
```

The "RUNNING" changes to a number of different things. 
Firebug's suggested xpath for the element is

```
//*[@id="state3"]
```

But, if i understand this xpath stuff correctly, will only check that the element is there, not that it contains the state I am looking for. 
How would I check for running in this example?

Comment: `//*[@id="state3"]` means "any element anywhere in the document that has an `id` attribute with the value `state3`".  If that's not specific enough, then no, it won't "work".

Answer (score 1):

Using Selenium's WebDriver class, you could check the value using the following code:

```
    WebElement state3Cell = driver.findElement(By.id("state3"));
    assertEquals("RUNNING", state3Cell.getText());
```

Comment: aha! That looks promising! I'll try it and get back to you